# Boost ASIO dropping UDP packets

Tags: sockets, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I've modified handle_send_to function of [BOOST ASIO example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp)  to look like this-

```
{   

ctr++;
cout<<"Counter: "<<ctr<<" data= "<<data<<endl;

socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,boost::bind(&server::handle_receive_from, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}
```

The intent is to basically increment the counter every time UDP connection is handled.

The test client is sending data like this-

```
for(;;){
ctr++;
printf("ctr= %lu\n",ctr);
snprintf(buf2, 10,"%lu",ctr);
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, buf2, strlen(buf2), 0,p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1)   
{
perror("client: sendto");
exit(1);
}
}
```

After running the test client, I see on the server side :

```
Counter= 358239 data= 369880
```

the data part shows the message #. The test client has indeed sent 369880 messages but as you can see counter is only 358239 (drop of 11641 messages).

What could be possibly wrong here?

Both hosts (sender and receiver, running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) are okay with resources- I don't see CPU, memory or network saturating.

The output of `netstat -su` looks like-

```
Udp:
    38569571 packets received
    1003583 packets to unknown port received.
    74619 packet receive errors
    267 packets sent
    RcvbufErrors: 74619
```

How do I troubleshoot large number of `packets to unknown port received` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you are basically doing the "saturation bombing" of the receiving interface I would expect the behavior like this in addition there is no guarantee that UDP will deliver the data and you may be saturating your network card as well.  Broadcom Cards for example have a very small send and receive buffers, so tweaking those might be useful.  I would suggest running `netstat -anc | egrep "Recv|<port number>"`.  And see what the size of the receive buffer is on the receiving end.

If you saturate the buffer you will start dropping packets.

As far as `packets to unknown port` you would need to do a `tcpdump` and analyze the output using [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org) or a similar tool to see what UDP traffic you are receiving in that category.